# Setting properties to the request context

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

How to set a property to the current request context? I'm trying to persist an audit trail (that contains request specific information) for all requests/response.

I was trying to do it in an implementation of ContainerResponseFilter (to avoid handling it in all the req methods) as below:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqCtx, ContainerResponseContext respCtx){
        ReqInfo info = (ReqInfo)reqCtx.getProperty("info_key");
        //..persist.
}
```

and setting this info in the Controller as shown below;

```
@Context
ContainerRequestContext reqCtx;

@POST
@Path("/some/path")
public Response foo(){
        ...
        ReqInfo info = new ReqInfo();
        reqCtx.setProperty("info_key", info);
        ...
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work, as I'm getting `Unable to find contextual data of type: ...ContainerRequestContext` error.

Is there anyway to set some properties to the request so that in can be accessed in the interceptor/Filter later?

Thanks

Comment: Is the trail specific to the request that you make with your client or to the request that initiated the action, e.g. a Resource method that calls the clients?

Comment: If the former, you can use a @RequestScoped CDI bean to store the trail

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to set the property for each request:

```
@Provider
public class DummyContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        requestContext.setProperty("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

And then access the property after the resource method has completed by calling:

```
@Provider
public class DummyContainerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getProperty("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx, but what I'm looking for a way to set property inside the controller (in a method is annotated with @Path) where application logic resides, coz the value I'm about set derives only at that stage.

Comment: You'll have to set an HTTP header and use a `ContainerResponseFilter` to convert it